# NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey crash after importing as a framework

Tags: ios, core-data, cocoapods, nscoding, nscoder

Before pulling out `MyClass` into a framework, I could save instances of `MyClass` into Core Data just fine.

Here's the implementation of `MyClass`:

```
open class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
  required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        stuffs = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "stuff") as? [Stuff] ?? []
    }

    open func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(stuffs, forKey: "stuffs")
    }
}
```

After pulling `MyClass` out into a framework with CocoaPods, I'm starting to get these crashes:

```
CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x1c019d4d0> , *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (MyClass) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked with userInfo of {
    "__NSCoderInternalErrorCode" = 4864;
}
```

Any idea why?...

Comment: EDIT: So after I deleted the app from my phone and installed again, everything works fine... But this isn't going to work if I need to push out an update?...o after I deleted the app from my phone and installed again, everything works fine... But this isn't going to work if I need to push out an update?...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By moving this class into a framework you've changed it's full name. Before that would have been something like `MyApp.MyClass` but now it's `MyFramework.MyClass`. Keyed archiving doesn't know they're the same, which is what caused your problem. Deleting and reinstalling got you past the problem because there was no longer any old data to decode.

You can tell the unarchive process how to resolve the conflict by using `setClass(:forClassName:`), so that you control class/name matching. You'd do something like

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(MyClass.self, forClassName: "MyApp.MyClass")
```

That'll fix decoding. To keep round trip encoding/decoding working you probably need to do the same thing for archiving, something like

```
NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("MyApp.MyClass", for: MyClass.self)
```

Comment: This is precisely what happened. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Quick follow up question: I’m trying to write some migration logic because there will be app installs with the old data and fresh ones (with no previous “dirty”) data. Do you have a quick way to check for these cases?

Comment: If you add in the right naming calls like this above, you'll be able to decode the existing data. There's no reason to stop using that that name. If you want, you could leave out the `NSArchiver` call and new archives will use the framework name.

Comment: Excellent solution. I had similar problem to OP. Was archiving/unarchiving, then moved the target class to a framework.